# I’m getting below error while I try to execute a workflow on Powercenter

Tags: workflow, informatica, informatica-powercenter

```
Transformation Parse Warning [<<P M Parse Warning>> <<Invalid constant sun-expression>> <<Expression Error>> [TO_DATE]:invalid string for converting to Date 
… t:TO_DATE(s:s:”,s:s:’YYYYMMDD’)
……….
AND SATIS_TARIHI = >>>> TO_DATE($$RUN_DATE,’YYYYMMDD’)<<<<];
```

How can I solve this?
This is the first time I encounter this error. Normally, this is a daily routine for our job. The parameter is successfully added to the mapping and all the other things seem okay. I’d appreciate your help.

I tried to start the workflow and got this error.

Comment: If you turn on verbose logging you should be able to see the data values in the log file. This will show you the values that Informatica can’t convert to dates which should allow you to debug the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a $$RUN_DATE in mapping. Currently its not defined in mapping or its null in parameter file.

You need to set a default value in mapping like `20221221` for today.

Or else you can set it up in a parameter file like this

```
[folder.workflow_name]
[folder.session_name]
$$RUN_DATE=20221221
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is your daily routine and up till now it has been working fine, I assume this is not a new development and no recent changes have been made. Apparantly PowerCenter got an invalid value for the parameter.

- Check you parameter file and how it gets generated.
- Was the process of generating paramfile executed without issues?
- Was there enough storage space?
- Can you verify the paramfile contents?
- Can you regenerate it?
- Can you modify it and provide some value manually?

Feel free to get back with some updates for more help if your problem won't get resolved by checking the items on the list above.